# What would you use to build a calendar that would run on IE11? (Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, grid

I'm currently working on a project that requires building a web page with a Calendar.

The Calendar should suppport booking (which means positioning boxes within the Calendar that span on a number of cells)

I built something simple using `css grid`, but later on I found out the customer uses `IE11`.

I tried using `AutoPrefix` to make the grid compatible, but it messed it up even worse and I think I'll waste more time adjusting then just using something other than grid.

I'm about to scrap my design and just go old school with `<table>` but before I do that, I wanted to ask for recommendations. Is there a better solution?

This is what it should look like:
[image]

Comment: You could maybe try this polyfill, https://github.com/FremyCompany/css-grid-polyfill  Not been updated for 2 years, but still might do what you need.  Worth a try!!?   Personally I would try an convince your customer to abandon ie11, even Microsoft don't like using it anymore..

Comment: I gave up on grid at this point. Looking for recommendations for something that is supported in IE11. Convincing him will be impossible. It's a big organization and they've been using IE for years.

Comment: Your solution to using `<table>` seems like your best bet.  Nothing wrong in using `<table>`.  Amazes me how it's large organisations that use outdated browsers, potentially opening them up to security issues and just bad user experience.

Comment: If I wanted to use table to show a grid, and then insert an appointment box that spans on 3 rows and 1 column. How would you do that?

Comment: `<td rowspan="3">`